# Problem with asp.net mvc route not firing when in <script> tag

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I cannot get the following route to fire when a url is requested from a script tag. I have the following route:

```
            // maps to "/cache/cachecontent/JavaScriptInclude/1/javascript"
            routes.MapRoute(
                null,
                "cache/{action}/{key}/{version}/{type}",
                new { controller = "Cache", action = "CacheContent", key = "", version = "", type = "" }
            );
```

I have a javascript script tag like:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/cache/cachecontent/JavaScriptInclude/1/javascript" />
```

Yet the route is not firing and the controller is not instantiated. If i drop the url into the address bar of the browser all is fine, but is not triggered from the javascript tag?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/cache/cachecontent/JavaScriptInclude/1/javascript"></script>
```

Instead of:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/cache/cachecontent/JavaScriptInclude/1/javascript" />
```

Notice the closing script tag at the end.

Comment: Always a gotcha! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/69913/why-dont-self-closing-script-tags-work

Answer (score 0):

I would look at FireBug and see what is loading. Are you using a virtual directory, if so the preceding slash will cause problems.